# Using EPPLUS package to read xls, how to ignore filtered data in C#

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

I am using EPPLUS (OfficeOpenXml) package to read an XLS file and load my database. I am struggling with below queries:

1. How to identify or ignore filtered out data coming from XLS? Suppose Excel file has 10 rows with numbers 1 through 10 and rows 1-5 are filtered out in XLS I would like to load rows 6-10 only.
2. Can I read CSV using EPPLUS?

Comment: `xls` is the old binary format, replaced by `xlsx` back in 2007. You can't read it with any library that targets xlsx and OpenXML.

Comment: What do you mean "load by database"? Are you trying to import the xls file into a database? Which one? Some, SQL Server for example, offer ways to import files from multiple formats. SQL Server's SSIS can read anything that comes with an ODBC or OLEDB driver, including Excel files, CSV, XML

Comment: Sorry I am successfully able to read a xlsx file and load my database SQL Server using EPPLUS package. Now I need to know how to ignore filtered rows and if its possible to read csv files.

Comment: Might help if you post your code of what you have tried so far.